# Как сделать рекурсивную функцию с map?

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, map

```
 Object.keys(this.dataLayer.dataBlocks.info).forEach(i =>{      
 let a = this.dataLayer.getEntityBy(i).entity; 

 a - массив прокси  

 a = a.child.map(e=>e.entity.child.map(e=>e.entity.child.map(e=>e.entity.urn)))
```

Как записать эту строку

```
(a = a.child.map(e=>e.entity.child.map(e=>e.entity.child.map(e=>e.entity.urn))))
```

в виде рукурсивной функции, которая работает, пока

```
  a.length > 0
```

?????

```
 a = a.child.map(e=>e.entity) - вернет массив прокси, которые связаны ссылками  типа `child` с родительскпрокой прокси, массив которых, это изначальны

 let a = this.dataLayer.getEntityBy(i).entity;
```

Comment: Каким образом изменяется `a.length`, и что это за массив со свойством `child`?

Comment: вы случайно не про deepMap говорите?

Comment: чувствую что скоро появится библиотека или серия статей, как программировать без циклов. каждый день вопросы, как реализовать что-то без циклов.

Comment: @OlmerDale такая библиотека есть. в функциональной парадигме вместо циклов рекурсия.